# 3d interactive graph linked with three sliders

Tags: slider, plotly-dash, scatter3d

I’m trying to create a 3d interactive graph linked with three sliders. I used dash plotly. But when I run this code, I get a blank 2d graph with sliders. If anyone can help me to find mistakes in my code, it would be very helpful.

Here is my data:

| A | C | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 191 | 11870402.57 | 150927.156 |
| 194 | 11534176.96 | 150926.613 |
| 200 | 8791715.569 | 150309.893 |
| 219 | 9058784.693 | 130344.409 |
| 193 | 11710374.76 | 150993.204 |
| 230 | 8966576.793 | 121803.204 |
| 196 | 11563137.82 | 147352.525 |
| 197 | 11559778.19 | 147360.662 |
| 232 | 8145250.015 | 134850.363 |
| 230 | 8960357.94 | 122119.87 |
| 241 | 8343604.908 | 118177.929 |

Here is the application layout:

```py
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

app = Dash(name)
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H4('Illustrations'),
    dcc.Graph(id='graph_scatter'),
    html.P('A:'),
    dcc.Slider(
        id='3d-scatter-plot-x-range-slider',
        min=df['A'].min(), max=df['A'].max(),
        value=df['A'].max()),
    html.P('B:'),
    dcc.Slider(
        id='3d-scatter-plot-y-range-slider',
        min=df['B'].min(), max=df['B'].max(),
        value=df['B'].max()),
    html.P('C:'),
    dcc.Slider(
        id='3d-scatter-plot-z-range-slider',
        min=df['C'].min(), max=df['C'].max(),
        value=df['C'].max())
])
```

And here is the callback:

```py
@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('3d-scatter-plot-x-range-slider', 'value'),
    Input('3d-scatter-plot-y-range-slider', 'value'),
    Input('3d-scatter-plot-z-range-slider', 'value')])
def update_bar_chart(slider_range_x, slider_range_y, slider_range_z):
    df = pd.read_csv('ABC.csv') # replace with your own data source
    low_x, high_x = slider_range_x
    low_y, high_y = slider_range_y
    low_z, high_z = slider_range_z
    
    mask = (df.A > low_x) & (df.A < high_x) & (
        df.B > low_y) & (df.B < high_y) & (
        df.C > low_z) & (df.C < high_z)

    fig = px.scatter_3d(mask,
                        x='A', z='C', y='B')
    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see some problem in your code.

- First: You set id in your dcc.Graph is `graph_scatter` but in you callback you set it is `graph`
- Second: You are using Slider so that you can not change the `low_x, low_y, low_z` but `high_x, high_y, high_y`. So that you can not use something like `low_x, high_x = slider_range_x`. Based on your code I revised as below:

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX])
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H4('Illustrations'),
    dcc.Graph(id='graph_scatter',figure={}),
    html.P('A:'),
    dcc.Slider(
    id='3d-scatter-plot-x-range-slider',
    min=df['A'].min(), max=df['A'].max(),
    value=df['A'].max()),
    html.P('B:'),
    dcc.Slider(
    id='3d-scatter-plot-y-range-slider',
    min=df['B'].min(), max=df['B'].max(),
    value=df['B'].max()),
    html.P('C:'),
    dcc.Slider(
    id='3d-scatter-plot-z-range-slider',
    min=df['C'].min(), max=df['C'].max(),
    value=df['C'].max())

    ])

@app.callback(
   Output('graph_scatter', 'figure'),
   [Input('3d-scatter-plot-x-range-slider', 'value'),
   Input('3d-scatter-plot-y-range-slider', 'value'),
   Input('3d-scatter-plot-z-range-slider', 'value')
   ])
def update_bar_chart(slider_range_x, slider_range_y, slider_range_z):
    high_x = slider_range_x
    high_y = slider_range_y
    high_z = slider_range_z
    dff = df[(df['A'] < high_x)&(df['B'] < high_y)&(df['C'] < high_z)]
    print(high_x)
    fig = px.scatter_3d(dff,x ='A', z='C',y='B')
    return fig
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Hoa, Thank you so much for taking the time to go through my code and resolve the issues. It's really helpful.